# Probability density function with an unknown constant

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I have a question that has a probability density function which is a function of two variables, x and y, and it also is defined in a unit square in the first quadrant. I assume its value is zero outside this region, but it does not specify this.

Here is the question below:
[image]

I am trying to figure out part (a).
Currently I am thinking that I can integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ in both variables X and Y, and this probability integral would be equal to the value 1. If this function is zero outside this unit square, I believe that the integral limits for both would be from 0 to 1.

So, this is what I am thinking I should do for part (a). I hope someone can let me know if my approach is correct for this or not.

For part (c), I am not sure how to calculate it because the X and Y variables are inequalities. I hope someone can give some insight to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, I am treating this as if it has been tagged with a [`self-study` tag](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Regarding (a), yes, the density must integrate to $1$, and it must be nonnegative everywhere. Integrate over that unit square and solve for $C$, or in other words, solve the following:
$$
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 (2x^2y + Cy^5 )dx dy = 1.
$$
Note that $\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} f(x,y) dx dy = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y) dx dy$ because $f$ is $0$ outside of this unit square.

Regarding (c), once you have the actual density with no unknown constants, you can use densities to integrate over regions for probabilities. If you integrate over the same region above, you will get $1$. That's like saying the probability of anything happening is $1$. So to find this particular probability, you need to integrate over a smaller region:
$$
\int_0^{.8} \int_0^{.6} (2x^2y + Cy^5) dxdy = 1.
$$
Note, in this equation, you would have to first replace $C$ with the value you calculated in part (a).

Comment: Hi Taylor, thanks a lot. Thanks for verifying part (a). In regards to part (c), If we find the C-constant over the unit square, then when we integrate over a smaller square so 0<=x<=0.6 and 0<=y<=0.8, we should get a probability value less than one if we use the C-value from part (a).

Comment: @Palu yep that's right!

Comment: Also, i was not aware of this particular tag you mention, the Self-Study tag.

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly realized no probability mass is placed outside $[0,1]^2$ by $f(x,y)$, so that restricting the integral bounds to $0$ and $1$ and setting the double integral equal to $1$ is indeed the correct approach.

For (c) note that $\mathbb{P}(X\leq x, Y\leq y)=\displaystyle\int_0^x\int_0^y f(u,v)dudv$.

Comment: Indicating why the lower limits of the integrals can be set to $0$ and not $-\infty$ might provide a useful clue concerning the solution of (a).

Comment: You don't want to use the same letter to refer to both the bounds of integration and the dummy variable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Edited my answer.